# How to add in Windows 10 a document without extension to the pinned list of an app?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, pinning

I like to add "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts" to the pinned documents of my text-editor (PSPad) on the taskbar.

Usually I only need to open a document and after that it shows ab in the recent documents list of this app in the taskbar. But the `hosts` file does not show up. I think because it has no extension?!

As you can see I have the document `linux_cmd.txt` added to this list:
[image]

I tried to search for this filename in `regedit` but could not find any entries. Where does Windows 10 save this list or is there an other way to add the `hosts` file to it?

Comment: "Where does Windows 10 save this list " - Registry.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force Windows 7 to pin a file with no extension to the Jump List for Notepad](http://superuser.com/questions/121584/force-windows-7-to-pin-a-file-with-no-extension-to-the-jump-list-for-notepad)

Comment: @Ramhound As I wrote. I searched in the registry, but was not able to find these entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it as follows:

- Opened `regedit`
- searched for `pspad` to find extensions that are default for this text editor
- found `.sh` with the default value `sh_auto_file`
- added a new key to Computer -> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT with the name `.`
- added the string value `sh_auto_file`
- signed out/in Windows 10 user to load registry changes
- opened `"C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"`
- and now its part of the recent documents list and can be pinned:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My solution is based on @mgutt's, with a few tweaks:

1. Create a new [registration file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Registry#.REG_files) with a text editor and save as `pin_noext.reg`:

   ```
   Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

   ; Add new key for files without extension
   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.]
   @="noext_auto_file"

   ; Retain file type name
   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\noext_auto_file]
   @="File"

   ; Retain blank document icon
   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\noext_auto_file\DefaultIcon]
   @="%SystemRoot%\\System32\\imageres.dll,2"

   ; Associate no-extension files with text editor (Notepad++)
   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\noext_auto_file\shell]
   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\noext_auto_file\shell\open]
   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\noext_auto_file\shell\open\command]
   @="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe\" \"%1\""
   ```
2. [Import](https://www.cezeo.com/tips-and-tricks/import-registry-file/) `pin_noext.reg` into the registry.
3. <strike>Reboot (or terminate-restart `C:\Windows\Explorer.EXE`)</strike>
   Refresh Windows Explorer (using [NirCmd](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html)): [`nircmd.exe shellrefresh`](https://nircmd.nirsoft.net/shellrefresh.html)
4. Open no-extension file (e.g., `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\HOSTS`) with chosen text editor (*Notepad++* in my case). The file will now appear in the text editor's [jump list](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/j/jumplist.htm).
5. Pin it! ( [Win7](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/210794-jump-lists-pin-unpin-items.html) ) ( [Win10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/43979-pin-unpin-items-jump-lists-windows-10-a.html) )